# Semantic web recommend-er system development

Tags: web, semantic-web, mahout-recommender

I'm beginning in semantic web. I want to develop a semantic web recommend-er system. The most important part of my project is moddeling. How can I start it? How long does it take? What soft-wares or tools can I use to develop that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Protege Ontology Editor to create your data models and create semantic rules with SWRL. Also you need a semantic rule engine too.

Comment: I have worked about semantics almost 5 years ago, so I could not give any resource.